# How to call onClick with VBA in HTML code?

Tags: html, vba, onclick, click

How can I call `onClick` in a HTML page?

Using Google, I got this code:

```
<img src="Imagens/lupa.gif" alt="Pesquisar Pasta" class="img" onclick="localizar();">
```

I'm using this VBA code:

```
Sub FazerLoginSite()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("https://webseal.itau/j146/pjuridico/")
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    On Error Resume Next
    .document.getElementById("username").Focus
    .document.getElementById("username").Value = "987268556"

    .document.getElementById("password").Focus
    .document.getElementById("password").Value = ""

    .document.All("button1").Click
    On Error GoTo 0
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    .document.getElementById("pasta").Focus
    .document.getElementById("pasta").Value = "140200586125"
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
   
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Set allInputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each element In allInputs
        If element.getAttribute("src") = "Imagens/lupa.gif" Then
            element.invokemember ("OnClick")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next element
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Debug.Print .LocationURL
End With

End Sub
```

How can I click on this code? In the web site this is an Image and the first part of the code I set my login and password, the I put a number to search, here called "Pasta", and finally I'm trying to click on this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any need to find the element. You can just call the same JavaScript function that `onClick` is calling using the `execScript()` function:

```
IE.document.parentWindow.execScript "localizar();", "javascript"
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS selector:**

Use a CSS selector to target the element of:

```
img[src='Imagens/lupa.gif']
```

This says element with `img` tag, having attribute `src` with value `'Imagens/lupa.gif'`.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the selector via the `querySelector` method of `document`.

```
ie.document.querySelector("img[src='Imagens/lupa.gif']").Click
```